# Who funds the Global Public Policy Initiative?

Tags: policy, germany, nato, funding

There's this Berlin-based think tank called the [Global Public Policy Initiative](https://www.gppi.net/about) (GPPI). Their website says they are an "independent" institute, which in layman's terms means they're trying to obfuscate who funds them.

The [Wikipedia page for the GPPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Public_Policy_Institute_(GPPi)) doesn't say where the funds come from (but does links it to the German Marshall Fund, which may be a clue).

My question: Who funds the GPPI? Directly, and possibly indirectly if it's by other funds with vague-sounding names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some browsing through their site yielded this:

> For longer-term research projects, we benefited from funding by the Volkswagen Foundation and the German Academic Scholarship Foundation. Other funders and clients include the Stiftung Mercator, Fritz Thyssen Foundation, the Open Society Foundations, and the German Federal Ministry for Economic Cooperation and Development.

That's from their "Rights & Democracy" page - there are other pages with similar lists.

https://www.gppi.net/issue-area/rights-democracy